# how to do HttpPost requests executing AsyncTask multiple times?

Tags: android-asynctask

### **Interface..**

```
public interface AsyncTaskCompleteListener<T>
{    public void onTaskComplete(T result);}
```

### **Async class**

```
public class HttpGetTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>
{

    private AsyncTaskCompleteListener<String> callback;

    public HttpGetTask(AsyncTaskCompleteListener<String> callback)
    {
       this.callback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings)
    {
       String url = strings[0];
       StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
       HttpClient client = BrainKing.getInstance().getHttpClient();
       HttpGet request = new HttpGet(IOUtils.getEncodedUrl(url));
       try
       {
           HttpResponse response = client.execute(request, BrainKing.getInstance().getLocalContext());
           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
           if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200)
           {
               BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(entity.getContent()));
               String line;
               while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
               {
                   builder.append(line).append("\n");
               }
           }
           else
           {
               // handle "error loading data"
           }
           entity.consumeContent();
       }
       catch (Exception ex)
       {
           // handle "error connecting to the server"
       }
       return builder.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result)
    {
       callback.onTaskComplete(result);
    }

}
```

### **MainActivity class..**

MainActivity class :
     public class Main extends Activity implements
     AsyncTaskCompleteListener{

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.confirmation);
//did http call here and got response 
progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", getResources().getString(R.string.loading_message), true, true);
new HttpGetTask(this).execute(url);
}
   @Override
    public void onTaskComplete(String result)
    {
        if (progressDialog != null)
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        //got the response here..Now i want to recall http on some parsed response until some predefined condition is met.. How to do it ??? need asap. Thanks in advance..
    }
 }
```

...how to do HttpPost requests executing AsyncTask multiple times ??..thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I fully understand your problem, but if you want to execute your AsyncTask multiple times until you get the expected response, I will go with something like that:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.confirmation);
  //did http call here and got response 
  progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", getResources().getString(R.string.loading_message), true, true);
  new HttpGetTask(this).execute(url);
}

@Override
public void onTaskComplete(String result) {
  if (progressDialog != null) progressDialog.dismiss();

  if(not expected result) {
    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", getResources().getString(R.string.loading_message), true, true);
    new HttpGetTask(this).execute(url);
  }
}
```

This way, every time your AsyncTask finish, the callback checks the output and, if it isn't what you are expecting, executes a new instance of your AsyncTask.